# Running bazel build with an aspect on test targets does not yield test output jars

Tags: bazel, bazel-aspect

running `bazel build //... \
--aspects some-aspect.bzl%some_aspect \
--output_groups=some_new_output,default`
 does not create test jars outputs.

on the other hand running bazel **test** does create the test jar outputs:

`bazel test //... \
--aspects some-aspect.bzl%some_aspect \
--output_groups=some_new_output,default`

How come?

This question was **updated** to reflect use of aspects:
The original question:

> running `bazel build //...` does not add test code to output jar.
>
> on the other hand `bazel test //...` builds the test code but also
>   runs it.
>
> Is there a way in bazel to build the test code without running the
>   tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a mistake in the values I gave the `--output_groups` flag.

It should have been `--output_groups=+some_new_output,+default`

The `default` can even be omitted:

`--output_groups=+some_new_output`

This flag is not documented at all. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2127) on this in bazel github repo.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for [--build_tests_only](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#flag--build_tests_only).

Comment: `--build_tests_only` seems not to be the answer I'm looking for, because with it the tests are still being run.

any other way to build the test code fully without running the tests?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "running bazel build //... does not add test code to output jar." ? What does "bazel test" build that "bazel build" doesn't?

Comment: Sure. from my experiments, I've noticed that ```bazel build //...``` does not build test jars (specifically jars originating from `scala_specs2_junit_test`),
But ```bazel test //...``` does build them

Comment: @Natan: Yes, but my repro attempt was unsuccesful: I cloned [@bazelbuild/rules_scala](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala), and with bazel-0.5.2 on Linux, I ran `bazel clean`, `bazel build //test:data_location_expansion`, `bazel test //test:data_location_expansion`. I also ran `find bazel-bin/test -name '*.jar' -not -path '*.runfiles/*'` after the latter two, and in both cases the result was just `bazel-bin/test/data_location_expansion.jar`. Do you see the same? How can I repro what you see?

Comment: I'v realized that I left out that I run the commands with aspects flags... I apologize for not giving out complete details about the problem. I found out what was the problem. I will update the question and provide an answer.